# I send an ISO 8583 request, but the switch is not responding,

Tags: finance, iso, pos, iso8583

Here is my request. The log from the server displays a different, wrong MTI. I think the server incorrectly decoded the data. What do you think the error is, causing the server to receive a different MTI?

```
    <log realm="channel/192.168.23.23:4988" at="Fri Jun 12 14:42:03 EAT 2020.15" lifespan="64ms">
          <connect>
            192.168.23.23:4988
          </connect>
        </log>
        <log realm="channel/192.168.23.23:4988" at="Fri Jun 12 14:42:17 EAT 2020.802" lifespan="1ms">
          <send>
            <isomsg>
              <!-- org.jpos.iso.packager.XMLPackager -->
              <header>6000000000</header>
              <field id="0" value="0100"/>
              <field id="2" value="9570059763383210"/>
              <field id="3" value="000000"/>
              <field id="4" value="000000023310"/>
              <field id="7" value="0612144217"/>
              <field id="11" value="137800"/>
              <field id="12" value="144217"/>
              <field id="13" value="0612"/>
              <field id="22" value="05"/>
              <field id="24" value="123"/>
              <field id="25" value="00"/>
              <field id="41" value="00001181"/>
              <field id="42" value="000060001000048"/>
              <field id="52" value="6062D6CB7E28BADC"/>
              <field id="62" value="22114455"/>
            </isomsg>
          </send>
        </log>
```

and the response is:

```
      <log realm="jpos-client-simulator" at="Fri Jun 12 14:42:47 EAT 2020.801">
          <info>
            Response time (ms):30000
          </info>
        </log>
        <log realm="jpos-client-simulator" at="Fri Jun 12 14:42:47 EAT 2020.803" lifespan="1ms">
          <error>
            Exception :null
          </error>
        </log>
```

Comment: The MTI seems fine. Please post the server logs.

Comment: What is your programming Language? JAVA?